# Alternative to JAXB for XML parsing

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, stax

I am currently using JAXB to parse XML documents, however i need a better performing XML processor.

Better = Faster and decrease memory footprint.

I have to process literally millions of separate XML documents.

I am using websphere application server v7 and java 6.

I have read Stax is the way to go via JAXP, but then i have seen articles saying JAXP is outdated.

If this is true, what are my althernatives to effeciently process millions of XML doucments (each XML doc is beteen 5Kb - 10Kb) without causing my application servers to crash with memory issues.

Comment: If you have memory issues with measly 5kB to 10 kB XML files then changing from JAXB to something else won't help you. As for speed: this depends on what you need to do with those XMLs. Do you keep those "millions" in memory all the time? Do you fail to clean up after each document? We'd need to see the unmarshalling code.

Comment: True, however when running at 600 tps processing literally millions of measly 5kb to 10kb XML docs, that does become an issue

Comment: At that rate: are you sure that keeping the data in millions of XML files is the best of the best? Even the OS will be bogged down with file access requests. As Mark suggests, investigate where the bottleneck really is.

Comment: We get XML via messaging, a third party system, not files

Comment: So what is the relation of a "transaction" (one of the 600 per second) to the millions? When do the messages arrive? Need to store them as XML data? (Might be a poor decision.) -- This is getting very muddy indeed. Mind drawing a clear picture how all of this connects?

Comment: wheres the mud? we have MDB's processing millions of MQ messages with XML payload. The XML is processed by JAXB. the processes up stream of the JAXB process are running at 600 TPS. The servers hosting the JAXB process ONLY do XML Unmarshalling, then send on further MQ messages down stream. The WAS servers hosting JAXB process are choked, eventually just doing GC. The bottleneck REALLY is JAXB processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first of all you should track the memory issues. How many of these XML are maintained in memory simultaneously, is it possible to keep only one (or at least some fairly small amount of XMLs) in memory simultaneously?
On servers Java processes usually takes at least 1Gb of memory so its not really clear whether the XML parsing is something that makes you process fail.

So I really believe you should work with a profiler here, before coming to conclusions that the XML parser should be changed.

There are a lot of parsers out there, 
You might try [woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/) which is a stax parser. 
Another option can be [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)
If you are looking for something that resembles JAXB, you might want to give a try to a [Simple XML parser](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Bottom line I believe you should first understand where does the issue exist, and if you resolve it, the chances are that you won't need to switch to another framework at all

Comment: Thanks for your time, we have profiled, identified XML unmarshalling is the bottleneck, now I am investigating alternatives

Comment: I understand jaxb is bad, I want something better that can cope with my workload

Comment: How do you understand that JAXB is bad?

Comment: its the only thing the WAS hosted code does. MDB reads XML MQ message, unmarshall then send on subsequent MQ message, routing of MQ messages downstream is based on XML content. The servers that fail are ONLY doing JAXB processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy within Java to read xml. Create a Groovy class within your Java source dir  if you are using maven

> src/main/groovy

and use Groovy XMLParser to parser to parse or  other class to write XML. It is much easier with Groovy to walk through the xml.

You can call the Groovy class as a Java class inside your Java program as Groovy compiles to Java class files

To do this via maven use

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
<artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generateStubs</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```